# Getting allways the same values when iterating using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

i try to collect some data using the following code:

```
import time
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

if __name__ == '__main__':
  
  print(f"Checking Browser driver...")
  os.environ['WDM_LOG'] = '0' 
  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1})    
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled') 
  srv=Service()
  driver = webdriver.Chrome (service=srv, options=options)      
  waitWD = WebDriverWait (driver, 10)         
  
  baseLink = "https://residentialprotection.alberta.ca/public-registry/Property"
  print(f"Working for {baseLink}")  
  driver.get (baseLink)     
  waitWD.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//input[@aria-owns="Municipality_listbox"]'))).send_keys("Calgary")
  waitWD.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[@id="show-results"]'))).click() 
  time.sleep(5) 
  countElems = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//tbody//tr[@role="row"]')
  print(len(countElems))
  for idx in range(len(countElems)):
    time.sleep(3)    
    elems = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//tbody//tr[@role="row"]')    
    elems[idx].click()
    time.sleep(3)
    soup = BeautifulSoup (driver.page_source, 'lxml')  
    worker = soup.find("label", {"for": "FileNumber"})
    wFileNumber = worker.find_next("td").text.strip()
    print(f"{idx}: {wFileNumber}")
    closeElem = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//a[@aria-label="Close"]')[-1]
    closeElem.click()
  driver.quit()
```

When you check the opened chrome-window it is opening all these 10 rows line by line and then parsing using bs4 for the file-number of this file. But in the output i allways get the same file-number 10 times (the file-number from the first row)

```
$ python temp2.py
Checking Browser driver...
Working for https://residentialprotection.alberta.ca/public-registry/Property
10
0: 21RU3557182
1: 21RU3557182
2: 21RU3557182
3: 21RU3557182
4: 21RU3557182
5: 21RU3557182
6: 21RU3557182
7: 21RU3557182
8: 21RU3557182
9: 21RU3557182
(selenium)
```

Why do i not get the different file-numbers like i can see it in the opened chrome-browser from selenium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion of @Andrej Kesely is good and quicker than using Selenium.

Anyway, if you want to know what is the issue in your code, on your resource when you are clicking on the item and table is opened, it is left in the DOM.

`find` method gets only first element for label FileNumber, so it would be always the label for first opened table.

To fix your code, you need always get last element, using `find_all` - it would be always last opened table.

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
worker = soup.find_all("label", {"for": "FileNumber"})[-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example how you can use their Ajax API to get the information:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://residentialprotection.alberta.ca/public-registry/Property"
api_url1 = "https://residentialprotection.alberta.ca/public-registry/Property/Search/"
api_url2 = (
    "https://residentialprotection.alberta.ca/public-registry/Property/GetSearchResults"
)

with requests.session() as s:
    s.headers.update(
        {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/119.0"
        }
    )

    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url).content, "html.parser")
    token = soup.select_one('[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]')["value"]

    s.headers.update({"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"})

    payload = {
        "__RequestVerificationToken": token,
        "SingleFamilyHomesChecked": ["true", "false"],
        "MultiFamilyHomesChecked": ["true", "false"],
        "RentalPropertiesChecked": ["true", "false"],
        "HomeTypeValidator": "valid",
        "SearchOptions": "CivicAddress",
        "CivicAddress.UnitSuiteApt": "",
        "CivicAddress.StreetNumber": "",
        "CivicAddress.StreetName": "",
        "CivicAddress.StreetSuffix": " ",
        "CivicAddress.StreetType": " ",
        "CivicAddress.StreetDirection": " ",
        "CivicAddress.Municipality": "Calgary",
        "CivicAddress.PostalCode": "",
        "CivicAddress.Validator": "Calgary",
    }

    s.post(api_url1, data=payload)

    for p in range(1, 4):  # <-- increase number of pages here
        print(f"Page = {p}")
        payload = {"sort": "", "page": p, "pageSize": "10", "group": "", "filter": ""}

        data = s.post(api_url2, data=payload).json()
        for d in data["Data"]:
            print(d["FileNumber"])
```

Prints:

```
Page = 1
18RU3379178
15RU1119234
14RU2261163
14RU5132686
21RU2856337
23RU9938182
22RU4803651
22RU7261796
22RU7681675
17RU8542659
Page = 2
20RU6818964
16RU9901648
23RU8282258
17RU8280630
20RU4105583
23RU2665576
21RU2679042
14RU4918882
23RU2415293
19RU2306982
Page = 3
22RU9776148
21RU5557379
15RU7567636
21RU5097769
18RU5498548
19RU3232994
21RU2503525
19RU8477433
21RU7136739
16RU6514843
```

Comment: great solution - but i only can give the answer-tag to one of you...